# Modify newrelic harvesting time

Tags: newrelic

I want to reduce the data ingested to newrelic (from our web application) to reduce our cost.
So i am thinking to increase harvesting time which is by default one minute.
I am unable to find anywhere how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to modify the agent harvest cycle frequency today, but you can tune the amount of sampling that occurs during each cycle (i.e - increase or reduce the number of spans captured within a trace). Below is that configuration for the java agent for example, but a similar flag should be available for other language agents as well.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/configuration/java-agent-configuration-config-file/#cfg-span-events-max-samples-stored

Comment: Other methods of modifying sampling of agents as well: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/data-apis/understand-data/event-data/new-relic-event-limits-sampling/

Comment: I had tried to reduce max_samples_stored from 2000 to 1000. i was hoping data ingestion will decrease by 50 % , but it is almost same . any idea why?